# How to cancel/change a function via Flex in External SWF? (Error #1063) [Flex, Air, As3]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex-spark

I'm getting swf from external website like the way:

```
import mx.events.FlexEvent;
private var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://blabla.com/test.swf?user=100004604079959");
private var loader3:Loader = new Loader();
private var loaded:Boolean = false
protected function init(event:Event = null):void
{
    if(!loaded) loadExternal();
}
private function loadExternal():void {
    loaded=true
    loader3.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader3.load(request);
    myUIComponent.addChild(loader3);
}


private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target.content);
    //mc.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.init);
}
```

But system giving this error : "Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on test/init(). Expected 0, got 1."

Because test.swf has it:

```
public function test()
    {
        if (stage)
        {
            this.init();
        }
        else
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.init);
        }
        return;
    }// end function

    private function init() : void
    {
            //blabla
    }
```

I can't edit it cuz I haven't access to edit external swf. So I must be change test() function from main app (I mean loader).

Can I do it? If yes, how?

Comment: Also I have a idea. If I can stop the start function (it's test()), I can call init() function on main stage. But how can I stop start function :3

Comment: Also I have idea one more. If I can put a stage in main stage, it won't give any error. How to put stage in stage?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this block of code:

```
private function init() : void
```

Event handler doesn't have required parameter parameters.

```
private function init(event: Event) : void
```

`Stage` is the same for internal and external class. Unfortunately `stage` is not defined for external class until you call `addChild()`.

Comment: First of all, thank you to answer. I know the problem about init. But I  can't edit external class. So I couldn't change init function. I have a  question about your answer, How to add swf to stage except addChild? I want it in stage.